# Implementing a queue using three stacks

Tags: java, stack, queue

This is just for fun so you will see tons of print statements for trouble shooting. I was hoping on slimming this down some and gain new ideas on what I have. This was a challenge question in a class I'm not in. I know the code i wrote is nightmare-ish anything to slim it down would be nice.

```
import java.util.*;


public class StackQueue {

    Stack stack1 = new Stack();
    Stack stack2 = new Stack();
    Stack temp   = new Stack();


    public void enqueue(String element) {
        stack1.push(element);
        System.out.println(stack1.toString() + "Stack1");
    }


        public void dequeue(){
            System.out.println(stack1.toString() + "\n\nStack1");

            if(!stack1.empty() & stack1.size()> 1 & !stack2.empty()) {           // if there are elements in both stacks
                System.out.println("IM IN THE BLOCK");
                while (!stack2.empty()) {
                    temp.push(stack2.pop());
                    System.out.println(temp.toString() + " TEMPP----");
                    System.out.println(stack2.toString() + " STACK 2---");
                }
                while (!temp.empty()) {
                    stack1.push(temp.pop());
                    System.out.println(stack1.toString() + " STACK1 ----");
                }
                System.out.println(stack1.pop() + " Has been removed");
                System.out.println(stack1.toString() + "STACK 1----");
                System.out.println(stack2.toString()+ "STACK 2----");

                if(stack2.empty()){
                    while (!stack1.empty()) {
                        temp.push(stack1.pop());
                        System.out.println(temp.toString() + " temp ----");
                    }
                    System.out.println(stack1.addAll(temp));
                    System.out.println(stack1.toString()+ "STACK ! ADD");
                    temp.removeAllElements();
                    System.out.println(temp.toString() + "TEMP _++++_+_+_+_");
                }
                }



           else if(stack1.empty()){

                System.out.println("\n\nstack1 is empty ");
                System.out.println(stack2.pop() + " Has been removed");
            }else {
                System.out.println("\n\n");
                while (!stack1.empty()) {
                    System.out.println(stack2.toString() + "Stack2 - second part");
                    stack2.push(stack1.pop());

                }
            System.out.println(stack1.toString()+ "stack1");
            System.out.println(stack2.toString()+"stack2");
            System.out.println(stack2.pop() + " Has been removed");
                    }

        }
    }






public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        StackQueue queue = new StackQueue();

        queue.enqueue("hey");
        queue.enqueue("I");
        queue.enqueue("am");
        queue.enqueue("Jeremiah");
        queue.enqueue("now");
        queue.dequeue(); //removes hey
        queue.dequeue(); //removes i
        queue.dequeue();// removes am
        queue.enqueue("one ");
        queue.enqueue("more");
        queue.enqueue("time");
        queue.dequeue();  // removes jeremiah

        // i had to reverse the stack1 order here 
        queue.dequeue(); // removes now
        //queue.dequeue(); // removes one
        queue.enqueue("FIRST");
        queue.dequeue();//removes FIRST


        System.out.println(queue.stack1.toString()  + " END S1");
        System.out.println( queue.stack2.toString() + " END S2");
        System.out.println(queue.temp.toString() + " END temp");


    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class StackQueue<T> {
    private Stack<T> writeStack = new Stack<T>();
    private Stack<T> readStack = new Stack<T>();

    public void enqueue(T element) {
        writeStack.push(element);
    }

    public T dequeue(){
        if (readStack.empty()) {
            while (!writeStack.empty()) {
                readStack.push(writeStack.pop());
            }
        }
        return readStack.pop();
    }
}
```

#### Algorithm

You only need two stacks. Always write to the `writeStack`, read from the `readStack`. If the latter is empty, copy everything over.

#### Naming

Use meaningful names, such as `writeStack` and `readStack` instead of `stack1` and `stack2`. Declare them `private`. A queue's user doesn't care about the internals. Import only what you need, in this case `java.util.Stack`.

#### Generics

The `Stack<T>` is a generic datatype, make use of it. Make your `StackQueue` generic as well. Instanciate it using

```
StackQueue<String> queue = new StackQueue<String>();
```

#### Return value

`dequeue()` should return a value. Print it with

```
System.out.println(queue.dequeue());
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem I found said to use three stacks. This was a challenge problem. However, your solution is great and advice thank you.

Comment: Also, why should dequeue return a value ?

Comment: If you insist on using a third stack, just add a `uselessStack` and don't use it. Also, a two-stack automaton is equivalent in power to a Turing machine. You *never* need more than two stacks.

Comment: From the most abstract point of view, a queue is a datastructure where you can put in values one by one, which are then stored internally and can later be retrieved in the same order. Hence, it must a least implement the methods `enqueue`, which takes a value and returns nothing, and `dequeue`, which does the opposite.

Comment: I understand its pointless to use three stacks. However, the problem in the book asked me to do so for a challenge.  I think adding uselessStack is cheating ha.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first I'd delete all the `print` statements and add at least one `return`, but you know that.

> ```
>     Stack stack1 = new Stack();
>     Stack stack2 = new Stack();
> ```

`Stack` is a generic datatype.  You should instantiate it as such.

```
    Stack<String> stack1 = new Stack<>();
    Stack<String> stack2 = new Stack<>();
```

This way there's no confusion about what it holds.

> ```
>         public void dequeue(){
>             System.out.println(stack1.toString() + "\n\nStack1");
>
>             if(!stack1.empty() & stack1.size()> 1 & !stack2.empty()) {           // if there are elements in both stacks
>                 System.out.println("IM IN THE BLOCK");
>                 while (!stack2.empty()) {
>                     temp.push(stack2.pop());
>                     System.out.println(temp.toString() + " TEMPP----");
>                     System.out.println(stack2.toString() + " STACK 2---");
>                 }
>                 while (!temp.empty()) {
>                     stack1.push(temp.pop());
>                     System.out.println(stack1.toString() + " STACK1 ----");
>                 }
>                 System.out.println(stack1.pop() + " Has been removed");
>                 System.out.println(stack1.toString() + "STACK 1----");
>                 System.out.println(stack2.toString()+ "STACK 2----");
>
>                 if(stack2.empty()){
>                     while (!stack1.empty()) {
>                         temp.push(stack1.pop());
>                         System.out.println(temp.toString() + " temp ----");
>                     }
>                     System.out.println(stack1.addAll(temp));
>                     System.out.println(stack1.toString()+ "STACK ! ADD");
>                     temp.removeAllElements();
>                     System.out.println(temp.toString() + "TEMP _++++_+_+_+_");
>                 }
>                 }
>
>
>
>            else if(stack1.empty()){
>
>                 System.out.println("\n\nstack1 is empty ");
>                 System.out.println(stack2.pop() + " Has been removed");
>             }else {
>                 System.out.println("\n\n");
>                 while (!stack1.empty()) {
>                     System.out.println(stack2.toString() + "Stack2 - second part");
>                     stack2.push(stack1.pop());
>
>                 }
>             System.out.println(stack1.toString()+ "stack1");
>             System.out.println(stack2.toString()+"stack2");
>             System.out.println(stack2.pop() + " Has been removed");
>                     }
>
>         }
> ```

I'm not following what `temp` does for you.  Consider

```
        public void dequeue() {
            if (stack2.empty()) {
                while (!stack1.empty()) {
                    String current = stack1.pop();

                    stack2.push(current);
                    System.out.println(current + " moved from stack1 to stack2.")
                }
            }

            System.out.println(stack2.pop() + " Has been removed");
        }
```

In this system, `stack1` is backwards, so we transfer it to `stack2`.  We do so only when `stack2` is empty, because otherwise it would get out of order.

If both stacks are empty, it will throw an exception on the last `pop`.  It's up to you if you `catch` it or allow it to propagate.  You could also check for `empty()` again.

Consider renaming `stack1` and `stack2` to have more meaningful names.  Something like `backward` and `forward` to keep track of the remove order.  So you reverse the `backward` stack onto the `forward` stack and remove from the `forward` stack.  I'd find that a lot more readable.

Note:  I didn't try to check correctness on your original algorithm, but I'm confident that this will work.

Comment: The problem required me to use three stacks which is why I used another stack called temp.